PySide6/PyQtGraph real-time plotting of sensor data
I am creating PySide6 app and I need to plot a vast amount of sensor data. The aim is that user has the feeling that the system is working real-time-ish. For example, if they tap a table next to an accelerometer, they should see vibration on the graph.
There are two plot types requires:

Scroll view: Number of plots inside QScrollArea, 2 traces per plot
Stacked view: All traces visible on two plots: 12 on one, the rest on the other.

Corner cases:

Acquisition at 250Hz, 16+12 channels to plot.
Acquisition at 16Hz, 256+12 channels to plot.

Duration of plot window can be up to 60s.
The approach I've applied:

Create a reader thread that collects MQTT data and saves it to NumPy array based circular buffer.
The main thread uses QTimer to update the graph every 100ms. Then it tries to read a circular buffer.
Access to buffer is protected with QMutex.

So, effective refresh rate should be 10Hz in ideal world.
I have read a number of tutorials on optimizing PyQtGraph plotting. E.g.:
Fast, Real-time plotting of points using pyqtgraph and a LiDAR
So, I have already applied:

Using setData
Disabling antialiasing setConfigOptions(antialias=False, useOpenGL=False)
Disabling autorange for Y axis and disabling mouse events:

        view_box.setYRange(0, 5.0, padding=0)
        view_box.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)


Additionally, I've set the following options:

   QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, True)
   QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
   QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(
       Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough
   )

So, I would like to ask you questions:

Is it the correct way to implement real-time plotting in PySide6/PyQtGraph?
Are there any other optimization techniques I am missing?
What else could be done? (Downsampling, preprocessing in backend is also an option as long as feeling of real time)
If nothing of the above applies: the link above states that plotting works smooth up to 100k points. Is that true?

Any advices appreciated.
Thanks!
EDIT:
As advised by @musicamante, I provide MREs:

No data acquistion, plotting from static buffer:

"""Minimal reproducible example 1"""

import sys
import logging
from time import time_ns
import numpy as np
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, QCoreApplication, Qt, QMutex, QMutexLocker
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QScrollArea,
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget, QtWidgets, mkPen, setConfigOptions, intColor

F_ACQ = 16
NUM_CHANNELS = 256
WINDOW = 60
NUM_SENSORS = 12
NS_TO_S = 1e-9
TRACES_PER_PLOT = 2
GRAPH_HEIGHT = 200
MARGIN = 1.05


class CircularBuffer:
    """1D circular buffer"""

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        # HACK: initialize with data
        self.buffer = np.arange(capacity) / F_ACQ
        self.head = 0

    def get(self):
        """Roll buffer and return"""
        return np.roll(self.buffer, -self.head)


class CircularBuffer2D:
    """2D Circular buffer"""

    def __init__(self, n_rows, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.n_rows = n_rows
        # HACK: Initialize buffer with data
        self.buffer = np.random.uniform(0, 5.0, (n_rows, capacity))
        self.head = 0

    def get(self):
        """Roll buffer and return"""
        # HACK to show graph moving:
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.capacity
        return np.roll(self.buffer, -self.head, axis=1)


class CircPacketArray:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Circular data packet"""

    def __init__(self, f_acq=100, window=60, num_channels=24):
        self._buffer_size = window * f_acq
        self.packet = {
            "time": CircularBuffer(capacity=self._buffer_size),
            "sensors": CircularBuffer2D(n_rows=NUM_SENSORS, capacity=self._buffer_size),
            "channels": CircularBuffer2D(n_rows=num_channels, capacity=self._buffer_size),
        }


class ScrollChart(QWidget):
    """Scroll chart"""

    def __init__(self, mutex, plot_packet):
        super().__init__()

        setConfigOptions(antialias=False, useOpenGL=False)

        self.mutex = mutex
        self.plot_packet = plot_packet

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.refresh_plot)

        self.init_ui(num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS)

        self.counter = 0
        self.start_time = 0

    def init_ui(self, num_channels):
        """Inititalize UI"""
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        num_channel_plots = int(np.ceil(num_channels / TRACES_PER_PLOT))
        num_sensor_plots = int(np.ceil(NUM_SENSORS / 3))

        canvas = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        canvas.setFixedHeight((num_channel_plots + num_sensor_plots) * GRAPH_HEIGHT * MARGIN)
        canvas.setAntialiasing(False)
        canvas.setOptimizationFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing)
        canvas.scene().setItemIndexMethod(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        canvas.ci.layout.setRowSpacing(0, 0)

        self.plots = []

        for idx in range(num_channel_plots):
            plot = canvas.addPlot(row=idx, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1, skipFiniteCheck=True)
            plot.setFixedHeight(GRAPH_HEIGHT)
            plot.setAutoVisible(x=False, y=False)

            self.plots.append(plot)

        self.channels = []

        for idx in range(num_channels):
            plot_idx = idx // TRACES_PER_PLOT
            self.channels.append(
                self.plots[plot_idx].plot(
                    pen=mkPen(intColor(idx, num_channels), width=1),
                    connect="auto",
                    name=idx,
                )
            )

        self.sensors = []
        for idx in range(num_sensor_plots):

            plot = canvas.addPlot(
                row=num_channel_plots + idx,
                col=0,
                rowspan=1,
                colspan=1,
                skipFiniteCheck=True,
            )

            plot.setFixedHeight(GRAPH_HEIGHT)
            plot.setAutoVisible(x=False, y=False)

            self.plots.append(plot)

        self.sensors = []
        for idx in range(NUM_SENSORS):
            plot_idx = idx // 3

            self.sensors.append(
                self.plots[num_channel_plots + plot_idx].plot(
                    pen=mkPen(
                        intColor(idx, NUM_SENSORS),
                        width=1,
                    ),
                    connect="auto",
                    name=idx,
                )
            )

        for plot in self.channels + self.sensors:
            view_box = plot.getViewBox()
            view_box.setYRange(0, 5.0, padding=0)
            view_box.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)

        # Add QLabel for debug
        self.debug_info = QLabel("FPS: -")
        layout.addWidget(self.debug_info)

        self.scroll_area.setWidget(canvas)

    def start_timer(self):
        """start timer"""
        self.timer.start(100)

    def refresh_plot(self):
        """Refresh plot"""
        self.plot()
        self.update_status()

    def plot(self):
        """Plot graph"""
        with QMutexLocker(self.mutex):
            dataset = self.plot_packet.packet

            t_data = dataset["time"].get()
            channels = dataset["channels"].get()
            sensors = dataset["sensors"].get()

            for idx, pen in enumerate(self.channels):
                pen.setData(x=t_data, y=channels[idx], _callSync="off", clear=True)

            for idx, pen in enumerate(self.sensors):
                pen.setData(x=t_data, y=sensors[idx], _callSync="off", clear=True)

    def update_status(self):
        """Display debug info"""
        if self.counter == 0:
            now = time_ns()
            elapsed_time = (now - self.start_time) * NS_TO_S
            self.start_time = now

            debug_text = f"FPS: {10/elapsed_time:2f}"
            logging.info(debug_text)
            self.debug_info.setText(debug_text)

        self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % 10


class MainScreen(QMainWindow):
    """Top level container"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MRE 1: Plotting only")

        width, height = QGuiApplication.instance().primaryScreen().size().toTuple()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, width, height)

        self.plot_buffer = CircPacketArray(f_acq=F_ACQ, num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS, window=WINDOW)
        self.mutex = QMutex()

        self.chart = ScrollChart(self.mutex, self.plot_buffer)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.chart)
        self.chart.start_timer()


def run():
    """Run Qt app."""
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, True)
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(
        Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough
    )

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainScreen()
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()



Data acquisition over Queue. Feeder, Worker in separate threads:

"""Minimal reproducible example 1"""

import sys
import logging
import queue
import threading
from time import time_ns, sleep
import numpy as np
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QThread, QTimer, QCoreApplication, Qt, QMutex, QMutexLocker
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QScrollArea,
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget, QtWidgets, mkPen, setConfigOptions, intColor

F_ACQ = 16
NUM_CHANNELS = 256
WINDOW = 60
NUM_SENSORS = 12
NS_TO_S = 1e-9
TRACES_PER_PLOT = 2
GRAPH_HEIGHT = 200
MARGIN = 1.05


class Feeder:
    """Data feeder"""

    def __init__(self, frequency, num_channels):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.running = False
        self.interval = 1.0 / frequency
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        self.thread.start()

    def run(self):
        """The function generates items and adds them to the queue."""
        while True:
            if self.running:
                data = generate_random_array(self.num_channels)
                self.queue.put(data)
            sleep(self.interval)  # Simulating some processing time

    def start(self):
        """Start feeder thread"""
        self.running = True

    def stop(self):
        """Stop feeder thread"""
        self.running = False

    def __del__(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.thread.join()

    def get_queue(self):
        """Return the queue.Queue instance"""
        return self.queue


def generate_random_array(num_channels):
    """Generate random data"""
    num_samples = 1 + NUM_SENSORS + num_channels

    data = np.random.uniform(0, 5.0, (num_samples,))
    data[0] = time_ns()

    return data


class CircularBuffer:
    """1D circular buffer"""

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.buffer = np.zeros(capacity, dtype=float)
        self.head = 0

    def append(self, value):
        """Append new element to buffer"""
        self.buffer[self.head] = value
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.capacity

    def get(self):
        """Roll buffer and return"""
        return np.roll(self.buffer, -self.head)


class CircularBuffer2D:
    """2D Circular buffer"""

    def __init__(self, n_rows, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.n_rows = n_rows
        self.buffer = np.zeros((n_rows, capacity), dtype=float)
        self.head = 0

    def append(self, values):
        """Append new element to buffer"""
        self.buffer[:, self.head] = values
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.capacity

    def get(self):
        """Roll buffer and return"""
        return np.roll(self.buffer, -self.head, axis=1)


class CircPacketArray:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Circular data packet"""

    def __init__(self, f_acq=100, window=60, num_channels=24):
        self._buffer_size = window * f_acq
        self.packet = {
            "time": CircularBuffer(capacity=self._buffer_size),
            "sensors": CircularBuffer2D(n_rows=NUM_SENSORS, capacity=self._buffer_size),
            "channels": CircularBuffer2D(n_rows=num_channels, capacity=self._buffer_size),
        }
        self.start_time = time_ns()

    def add(self, packet):
        """Add new corti packet and dispatch it per channel"""
        self.packet["time"].append(calc_time(packet[0], self.start_time))
        self.packet["sensors"].append(packet[1:13])
        self.packet["channels"].append(packet[13:])


def calc_time(data, start_time):
    """Calc elapsed time in [s]"""
    return (data - start_time) * NS_TO_S


class ScrollChart(QWidget):
    """Scroll chart"""

    def __init__(self, mutex, plot_packet):
        super().__init__()

        setConfigOptions(antialias=False, useOpenGL=False)

        self.mutex = mutex
        self.plot_packet = plot_packet

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.refresh_plot)

        self.init_ui(num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS)

        self.counter = 0
        self.start_time = 0

    def init_ui(self, num_channels):
        """Inititalize UI"""
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        num_channel_plots = int(np.ceil(num_channels / TRACES_PER_PLOT))
        num_sensor_plots = int(np.ceil(NUM_SENSORS / 3))

        canvas = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        canvas.setFixedHeight((num_channel_plots + num_sensor_plots) * GRAPH_HEIGHT * MARGIN)
        canvas.setAntialiasing(False)
        canvas.setOptimizationFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing)
        canvas.scene().setItemIndexMethod(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        canvas.ci.layout.setRowSpacing(0, 0)

        self.plots = []

        for idx in range(num_channel_plots):
            plot = canvas.addPlot(row=idx, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1, skipFiniteCheck=True)
            plot.setFixedHeight(GRAPH_HEIGHT)
            plot.setAutoVisible(x=False, y=False)

            self.plots.append(plot)

        self.channels = []

        for idx in range(num_channels):
            plot_idx = idx // TRACES_PER_PLOT
            self.channels.append(
                self.plots[plot_idx].plot(
                    pen=mkPen(intColor(idx, num_channels), width=1),
                    connect="auto",
                    name=idx,
                )
            )

        self.sensors = []
        for idx in range(num_sensor_plots):

            plot = canvas.addPlot(
                row=num_channel_plots + idx,
                col=0,
                rowspan=1,
                colspan=1,
                skipFiniteCheck=True,
            )

            plot.setFixedHeight(GRAPH_HEIGHT)
            plot.setAutoVisible(x=False, y=False)

            self.plots.append(plot)

        self.sensors = []
        for idx in range(NUM_SENSORS):
            plot_idx = idx // 3

            self.sensors.append(
                self.plots[num_channel_plots + plot_idx].plot(
                    pen=mkPen(
                        intColor(idx, NUM_SENSORS),
                        width=1,
                    ),
                    connect="auto",
                    name=idx,
                )
            )

        for plot in self.channels + self.sensors:
            view_box = plot.getViewBox()
            view_box.setYRange(0, 5.0, padding=0)
            view_box.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)

        # Add QLabel for debug
        self.debug_info = QLabel("FPS: -")
        layout.addWidget(self.debug_info)

        self.scroll_area.setWidget(canvas)

    def start_timer(self):
        """start timer"""
        self.timer.start(100)

    def refresh_plot(self):
        """Refresh plot"""
        self.plot()
        self.update_status()

    def plot(self):
        """Plot graph"""
        with QMutexLocker(self.mutex):
            dataset = self.plot_packet.packet

            t_data = dataset["time"].get()
            channels = dataset["channels"].get()
            sensors = dataset["sensors"].get()

            for idx, pen in enumerate(self.channels):
                pen.setData(x=t_data, y=channels[idx], _callSync="off", clear=True)

            for idx, pen in enumerate(self.sensors):
                pen.setData(x=t_data, y=sensors[idx], _callSync="off", clear=True)

    def update_status(self):
        """Display debug info"""
        if self.counter == 0:
            now = time_ns()
            elapsed_time = (now - self.start_time) * NS_TO_S
            self.start_time = now

            debug_text = f"FPS: {10/elapsed_time:2f}"
            logging.info(debug_text)
            self.debug_info.setText(debug_text)

        self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % 10


class MainScreen(QMainWindow):
    """Top level container"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MRE 1: Plotting only")

        width, height = QGuiApplication.instance().primaryScreen().size().toTuple()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, width, height)

        self.plot_buffer = CircPacketArray(f_acq=F_ACQ, num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS, window=WINDOW)
        self.mutex = QMutex()
        self.worker = Worker(self.mutex, self.plot_buffer)
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.chart = ScrollChart(self.mutex, self.plot_buffer)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.chart)
        self.chart.start_timer()
        self.worker_thread.start()


class Worker(QObject):
    """Communicator class"""

    def __init__(self, mutex, plot_buffer):
        super().__init__()
        self.mutex = mutex
        self.plot_buffer = plot_buffer
        self.feeder = Feeder(frequency=F_ACQ, num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS)

    def run(self):
        """Run communication thread"""
        logging.error("Worker running")
        self.feeder.start()
        data_queue = self.feeder.get_queue()

        while True:
            packet = data_queue.get()
            with QMutexLocker(self.mutex):
                self.plot_buffer.add(packet)


def run():
    """Run Qt app."""
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, True)
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(
        Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough
    )

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainScreen()
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()



Acquisition over MQTT, worker is separate thread, data source as independent app:

GUI:
"""Minimal reproducible example 1"""

import sys
import logging
from time import time_ns
import numpy as np
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QThread, QTimer, QCoreApplication, Qt, QMutex, QMutexLocker
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QScrollArea,
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget, QtWidgets, mkPen, setConfigOptions, intColor

F_ACQ = 250
NUM_CHANNELS = 16
WINDOW = 60
NUM_SENSORS = 12
NS_TO_S = 1e-9
TRACES_PER_PLOT = 2
GRAPH_HEIGHT = 200
MARGIN = 1.05

MQTT_BROKER = "localhost"
MQTT_PORT = 1883

PLOT_START_TOPIC = "v1/command/plot_start"
PLOT_STOP_TOPIC = "v1/command/plot_stop"
PLOT_DATA_TOPIC = "v1/plot_data"

class CircularBuffer:
    """1D circular buffer"""

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.buffer = np.zeros(capacity, dtype=float)
        self.head = 0

    def append(self, value):
        """Append new element to buffer"""
        self.buffer[self.head] = value
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.capacity

    def get(self):
        """Roll buffer and return"""
        return np.roll(self.buffer, -self.head)


class CircularBuffer2D:
    """2D Circular buffer"""

    def __init__(self, n_rows, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.n_rows = n_rows
        self.buffer = np.zeros((n_rows, capacity), dtype=float)
        self.head = 0

    def append(self, values):
        """Append new element to buffer"""
        self.buffer[:, self.head] = values
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.capacity

    def get(self):
        """Roll buffer and return"""
        return np.roll(self.buffer, -self.head, axis=1)


class CircPacketArray:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Circular data packet"""

    def __init__(self, f_acq=100, window=60, num_channels=24):
        self._buffer_size = window * f_acq
        self.packet = {
            "time": CircularBuffer(capacity=self._buffer_size),
            "sensors": CircularBuffer2D(n_rows=NUM_SENSORS, capacity=self._buffer_size),
            "channels": CircularBuffer2D(n_rows=num_channels, capacity=self._buffer_size),
        }
        self.start_time = time_ns()

    def add(self, packet):
        """Add new corti packet and dispatch it per channel"""
        self.packet["time"].append(calc_time(packet[0], self.start_time))
        self.packet["sensors"].append(packet[1:13])
        self.packet["channels"].append(packet[13:])


def calc_time(data, start_time):
    """Calc elapsed time in [s]"""
    return (data - start_time) * NS_TO_S


class ScrollChart(QWidget):
    """Scroll chart"""

    def __init__(self, mutex, plot_packet):
        super().__init__()

        setConfigOptions(antialias=False, useOpenGL=False)

        self.mutex = mutex
        self.plot_packet = plot_packet

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.refresh_plot)

        self.init_ui(num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS)

        self.counter = 0
        self.start_time = 0

    def init_ui(self, num_channels):
        """Inititalize UI"""
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        num_channel_plots = int(np.ceil(num_channels / TRACES_PER_PLOT))
        num_sensor_plots = int(np.ceil(NUM_SENSORS / 3))

        canvas = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        canvas.setFixedHeight((num_channel_plots + num_sensor_plots) * GRAPH_HEIGHT * MARGIN)
        canvas.setAntialiasing(False)
        canvas.setOptimizationFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DontAdjustForAntialiasing)
        canvas.scene().setItemIndexMethod(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        canvas.ci.layout.setRowSpacing(0, 0)

        self.plots = []

        for idx in range(num_channel_plots):
            plot = canvas.addPlot(row=idx, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1, skipFiniteCheck=True)
            plot.setFixedHeight(GRAPH_HEIGHT)
            plot.setAutoVisible(x=False, y=False)

            self.plots.append(plot)

        self.channels = []

        for idx in range(num_channels):
            plot_idx = idx // TRACES_PER_PLOT
            self.channels.append(
                self.plots[plot_idx].plot(
                    pen=mkPen(intColor(idx, num_channels), width=1),
                    connect="auto",
                    name=idx,
                )
            )

        self.sensors = []
        for idx in range(num_sensor_plots):

            plot = canvas.addPlot(
                row=num_channel_plots + idx,
                col=0,
                rowspan=1,
                colspan=1,
                skipFiniteCheck=True,
            )

            plot.setFixedHeight(GRAPH_HEIGHT)
            plot.setAutoVisible(x=False, y=False)

            self.plots.append(plot)

        self.sensors = []
        for idx in range(NUM_SENSORS):
            plot_idx = idx // 3

            self.sensors.append(
                self.plots[num_channel_plots + plot_idx].plot(
                    pen=mkPen(
                        intColor(idx, NUM_SENSORS),
                        width=1,
                    ),
                    connect="auto",
                    name=idx,
                )
            )

        for plot in self.channels + self.sensors:
            view_box = plot.getViewBox()
            view_box.setYRange(0, 5.0, padding=0)
            view_box.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)

        # Add QLabel for debug
        self.debug_info = QLabel("FPS: -")
        layout.addWidget(self.debug_info)

        self.scroll_area.setWidget(canvas)

    def start_timer(self):
        """start timer"""
        self.timer.start(100)

    def refresh_plot(self):
        """Refresh plot"""
        self.plot()
        self.update_status()

    def plot(self):
        """Plot graph"""
        #with QMutexLocker(self.mutex):
        dataset = self.plot_packet.packet

        t_data = dataset["time"].get()
        channels = dataset["channels"].get()
        sensors = dataset["sensors"].get()

        for idx, pen in enumerate(self.channels):
            pen.setData(x=t_data, y=channels[idx], _callSync="off", clear=True)

        for idx, pen in enumerate(self.sensors):
            pen.setData(x=t_data, y=sensors[idx], _callSync="off", clear=True)

    def update_status(self):
        """Display debug info"""
        if self.counter == 0:
            now = time_ns()
            elapsed_time = (now - self.start_time) * NS_TO_S
            self.start_time = now

            debug_text = f"FPS: {10/elapsed_time:2f}"
            logging.info(debug_text)
            self.debug_info.setText(debug_text)

        self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % 10


class MainScreen(QMainWindow):
    """Top level container"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MRE 1: Plotting only")

        width, height = QGuiApplication.instance().primaryScreen().size().toTuple()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, width, height)

        self.plot_buffer = CircPacketArray(f_acq=F_ACQ, num_channels=NUM_CHANNELS, window=WINDOW)
        self.mutex = QMutex()
        self.worker = Worker(self.mutex, self.plot_buffer)
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.chart = ScrollChart(self.mutex, self.plot_buffer)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.chart)
        self.chart.start_timer()
        self.worker_thread.start()


class Worker(QObject):
    """Communicator class"""

    def __init__(self, mutex, plot_buffer):
        super().__init__()
        self.mutex = mutex
        self.plot_buffer = plot_buffer
        self.client = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv5)
        self.client.connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT)
        self.client.message_callback_add(PLOT_DATA_TOPIC, self.on_plot_data)
        self.client.loop_start()

    def run(self):
        """Run communication thread"""
        logging.error("Worker running")
        self.plot_start()

    def on_plot_data(self, client, userdata, message):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """Plot data callback"""
        data = np.frombuffer(message.payload)
        #with QMutexLocker(self.mutex):
        self.plot_buffer.add(data)

    def plot_start(self):
        """Request data for plotting"""
        self.client.subscribe(PLOT_DATA_TOPIC)
        self.client.publish(PLOT_START_TOPIC, "", qos=1)

    def plot_stop(self):
        """Stop data"""
        self.client.publish(PLOT_STOP_TOPIC, "", qos=1)
        self.client.unsubscribe(PLOT_DATA_TOPIC)


def run():
    """Run Qt app."""
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, True)
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(
        Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough
    )

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainScreen()
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()

Results at 16Hz, 256+12 Channels:

No acquisition, refresh rate: ca. 7Hz
Queue, refresh rate: ca.4Hz
MQTT, refresh rate <3Hz


There could be many reasons for which you get that performance, including time required to write the data (which would block reading from the main thread), or bad implementation of the sensor reading or numpy access. I suggest you to take your time and provide a [mre].

@musicamante Thanks for comment. I added MREs for 3 cases: No acquisition, acquisition using Queue and over MQTT.
I have also code for MQTT Feeder, but it didn't fit the body character limitations.

I found one huge bottleneck: changing x-axis. When I frozen x-axis range, i can get 5-6Hz with MQTT
